# How to combine pause and unpause game button in unity [C#] with GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity C# game and I want my pause button to be GUI [with the pause and unpause image displayed on click].

Any help would be great.Thank you so much!!!

Comment: what did you already tried? are you using new UI or legacy GUI?

Comment: (1) click "add canvas"  (2) click "add Button".  You're done.  **Note this important tip** ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36268018/294884

Comment: @JoeBlow That answer is from March, is it still using the wrong settings?

Comment: yes, you must change it as it says in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create new Button object, and add proper method for displaying correct image. Something like this:

```
public class ButtonStateHandler:MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClicked;
    public Button myBtn;
    public Sprite Play;
    public Sprite Pause;

    public void Click(){
        changeState();
    }
    private void changeState(){
        isClicked = !isClicked;
        if(isClicked)       myBtn.image.sprite = Play;
        else myBtn.image.sprite = Pause;
        }
}
```

And then remember to add Click method in the inspector to OnClick list on Play/Pause button.

[image]

Comment: There is a minor typos.                                                                             but hey thanks a lot it worked. :)