# Unity UI Canvas size issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I create a UI Text object, Canvas size is so big that my main game area is not visible. I somehow figured out how to scale it down to smaller size but the text is very blurry when its size is reduced.

Screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rmal.jpg

Comment: You should put a screenshot of this problem. Also show your Canvas and UI Text settings.

Comment: @Programmer Did that.

Comment: Canvas default size will take your current screen resolution as units in the IDE. But when running the game in Unity the Canvas will usually auto resized to the screen size.

Comment: "big that my main game area is not visible" I asked for a picture of the big canvas but I didn't get one. I can't tell what's going on without that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scaling GUI.TextArea with Screen Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267658/scaling-gui-textarea-with-screen-size)