# Display GUI with incrementing variable each collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GUI on my scene saying "Capsules Collected: 0/10" and a capsule object which has Collider that whenever the player enters the capsule , the capsule will be destroyed and the Capsules Collected will be increased by 1.

The Destroy Works well, the GUI isnt displaying. What is wrong with my code?

Here's my Code, I assigned this C# script on the Player itself:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class CapsuleGET : MonoBehaviour {
    int capscore=0;

    void Start(){
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        capscore =capscore+1;
    }

    void Update(){
        GUILayout.Label("Capsules Collected: "+capscore+"/10");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Miguel - you can't really use the "ancient GUI system" now, it is totally deprecated.  The new system is incredibly easier ......... here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36268018/294884

Comment: As a side note I would not recommend setting the value of the label on **every update** instead do it inside the `OnTriggerEnter` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this .. very easy

```
using Unity.UI;
public class CapsuleGET
   public Text displayScore;  // DRAG to connect in Editor

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        capscore =capscore+1;

        displayScore.text = capscore.ToString();
```

1 - click to add canvas (don't forget to select 'scale with screen size')

[image]

2 - click to add Text, position as you want.

3 - in your script, "public Text score"

4 - **drag** from the "Text" to that variable

[explanation with diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36268018/294884)

Comment: I cant see the Add Canvas, im using Unity 4.3.3f1

Comment: hi @MiguelGauranoPunzal  (1) see edited answer (2) additionally, you must change to Unity5.  Unity4 no longer works.  There's absolutely no reason to not download Unity5.

Comment: Thanks bro, i already downloaded Unity5 and it solves my problem :)